# Matplotlib plots no line plots; crosses, circles and triangles work

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm trying to plot some measurement data with Matplotlib.
With the code shown below i get the plot window and gui but no plot is drawn. If i change the plot kind to circles or crosses it works just fine.

```
# coding=utf-8
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

with open("AgPVP8.2.171g1L#2.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")

    frequencies = []
    phases = []

    for row in reader:
        frequency = float(row[0])
        phase = float(row[4])

        frequencies.append(frequency)
        phases.append(phase)

plt.plot([frequencies], [phases], "b-")
plt.xscale("log")
plt.show()
```

Comment: why do you use `[]` if you do `plt.plot(frequencies, phases, "b-")` it does not work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`plt.plot(x,y)` requires `x` and `y` to be lists (or in general sequences) or arrays. 
Here, you are trying to plot a list of a list, i.e. `[x]` is not the same as `x`.
So in your code you need to replace `plt.plot([frequencies], [phases], "b-")` with

```
plt.plot(frequencies, phases, "-b")
```

The complete code should then look like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

with open("AgPVP8.2.171g1L#2.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")

    frequencies = []
    phases = []

    for row in reader:
        frequency = float(row[0])
        phase = float(row[4])

        frequencies.append(frequency)
        phases.append(phase)

plt.plot(frequencies, phases, "b-")
plt.xscale("log")
plt.show()
```

I would suggest to have a look at [`numpy.loadtxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) or `numpy.genfromtxt`. Both would make is much easier to read in a csv file, e.g. in this case

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

frequencies, phases = np.loadtxt("AgPVP8.2.171g1L#2.csv", unpack=True, usecols = (0,4), delimiter=",")

plt.plot(frequencies, phases, "b-")
plt.xscale("log")
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that frequencies and phases only exist in the scope of `with open(...`, you must place it within this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import csv

with open("AgPVP8.2.171g1L#2.csv") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=",")

    frequencies = []
    phases = []

    for row in reader:
        frequency = float(row[0])
        phase = float(row[4])

        frequencies.append(frequency)
        phases.append(phase)
    plt.plot(frequencies, phases, "-b")
    plt.xscale("log")
    plt.show()
```

Comment: `csvfile` only exists within the `with` context. All other variables are global here. It is therefore no problem at all to do the plotting outside the context - I think one should even do it such that the file can be closed before the plot is shown.